# How can I allow user interaction on a "out of bounds" view?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, view, storyboard

I am developing a mobile app on iOS and I'm trying to work with a hidden menu which shows up when the user taps an input. I am using a container view that is hidden and has UITableViewController inside. Here is an screenshot of the storyboard.

[Here's an screenshot of the storyboard.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NLGV.png) The selected one is the container view.

[Here's a Video to show what's happening.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LKMeWIN4hYs&feature=youtu.be) As you can see only de little part that is inside the view in the storyboard can be clicked.

Is there any way to make the rest of the container view respond to user interactions, without having to change de size of the view controller?

Comment: Use a UISearchController.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your issue you can use this to animate your view 
https://github.com/nathangitter/interactive-animations

This is very simple and easy way to add this animation.